# I am getting exception while running Scala Worksheet in intellij

Tags: scala

I am using Scala 2.11.8 and running simple program in Scala worksheet.

I am getting the below error. Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

> Internal error: null
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ClientEventProcessor.process(ClientEventProcessor.scala:22)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:47)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.handle$(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:37)
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.handle(RemoteServerRunner.scala:14)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$5(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:30)

Comment: Your Scala version is fine. Please update jdk then it may work fine.

Comment: Also try to update intellij IDEA

Comment: Try updating your Scala version as well as your IntelliJ version!! Actually it might happen that you are using old version of Scala and it error still persist let us know!!